# How to add a label to the combination of the url pattern and http method?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

In our project, we must register all our endpoints with their related HTTP method to the third-party service. To organize the list of endpoints, we want to add labels to the combination of the URL and HTTP method. But I can't find a way to make this happen:/

Can anyone help me?

for more detail:

I have this path:

```
path("brands/", views.GetBrand.as_view({"get": "list", "post": "create"}))
```

I want to extract this information from the above line:

```
[
    {
        "label": ["get-brand", "brand-management"],
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "api/brands/"
    },
    {
        "label": ["create-brand", "brand-management"],
        "method": "post",
        "url": "api/brands/"
    }
```

I assumed that we can read the labels from the attribute that we set on the class view, can't I?!